# Ethereum private network mining

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, ethereum

1) I setup a private ethereum network using the following command

```
$geth --genesis <genesis json file path> --datadir <some path to an empty  
folder> --networkid 123 --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 console
```

2) Created an account

3) Then, started the miner using miner.start() command.

After a while ethers were getting added automatically to my account, but I don’t have any pending transaction in my private network. So from where could my miners are getting the ethers?

Even though, I didn’t instantiate any transactions in my network, I could see the some transaction being recorded in the logs, once I start the miner.

The log is as follows:

```
I0118 11:59:11.696523 9427 backend.go:584] Automatic pregeneration of ethash  
DAG ON (ethash dir: /Users/minisha/.ethash)
I0118 11:59:11.696590 9427 backend.go:591] checking DAG (ethash dir:   
/Users/minisha/.ethash)
I0118 11:59:11.696728 9427 miner.go:119] Starting mining operation (CPU=4 
TOT=5)
true
> I0118 11:59:11.703907 9427 worker.go:570] commit new work on block 1 with 0
txs & 0 uncles. Took 7.109111ms
I0118 11:59:11.704083 9427 ethash.go:220] Generating DAG for epoch 0 (size 
1073739904) (0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
I0118 11:59:12.698679 9427 ethash.go:237] Done generating DAG for epoch 0, it  
took 994.61107ms
I0118 11:59:15.163864 9427 worker.go:349]
```

And my genesis block code is as follows:

```
{
“nonce”: “0xdeadbeefdeadbeef”,
“timestamp”: “0x0”,
“parentHash”: 
“0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000”,
“extraData”: “0x0”,
“gasLimit”: “0x8000000”,
“difficulty”: “0x400”,
“mixhash”: 
“0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000”,
“coinbase”: “0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333”,
“alloc”: {
}
}
```

Since my network is isolated and have only one node (no peers), I am quite confused with this behaviour. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your client is mining empty blocks (containing no transactions) and getting rewards for mined blocks what is 5 ETH per block.

If you want to prevent empty block in your private blockchain you should consider using **eth** client (C++ implementation).

In case of **geth** client you can use a JavaScript script that will modify client's behavior. Any script can be loaded with `js` command: `geth js script.js`.

```javascript
var mining_threads = 1

function checkWork() {
    if (eth.getBlock("pending").transactions.length > 0) {
        if (eth.mining) return;
        console.log("== Pending transactions! Mining...");
        miner.start(mining_threads);
    } else {
        miner.stop(0);  // This param means nothing
        console.log("== No transactions! Mining stopped.");
    }
}

eth.filter("latest", function(err, block) { checkWork(); });
eth.filter("pending", function(err, block) { checkWork(); });

checkWork();
```

Comment: Theoretically, a block will be created only if there is a transaction, so confused by that behaviour. However, this happens only in private network, isn't?

Comment: No. Empty blocks happen also in the public network. See e.g. http://etherscan.io/blocks.
The network is organized in the way blocks are mined regularly, every ~17 s. It can happen there are no transaction in this period.

Comment: Thanks very much for this script ... it works well. With the latest version of the eth package the stop() method does not take a parameter and loading the script fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [EmbarkJS](https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework) which can run `geth` client with `mineWhenNeeded` option on private network. It will only mine when new transactions come in.